# Coding Kinect in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, kinect

I am coding a Kinect 2 sensor (for Xbox One) in Eclipse using Java. I am using libraries from this site: http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/VideoFrame.php that provide libraries and classes for Kinect, the Skeleton within Kinect, and other pieces that help one create a program using the Kinect.

The problem I am having is printing something to the console or even displaying a shape on the screen. My goal is to create a shape on the screen to be a bounds that if the user's fingers move outside of it, then it will display a message on the screen. However, when I use the Java Frame class, only the Kinect window shows. I am not sure if anyone has worked with this but any help or direction would be appreciated.

Here is my code thus far:

```
        // Displays loading process at 20% for Kinect video
        setLoadingProgress("Kinect is initalizing ...", 20);
        testkinect = new Kinect();

        if(!testkinect.start(J4KSDK.COLOR)){
            // Error check if Kinect is not running properly
            DWApp.showErrorDialog("ERROR", "<html><center><br>ERROR: The Kinect device could not be initialized.<br><br>1. Check if the Microsoft's Kinect SDK was succesfully installed on this computer.<br> 2. Check if the Kinect is plugged into a power outlet.<br>3. Check if the Kinect is connected to a USB port of this computer.</center>");
            //System.exit(0); 
        }

        // Initializing and opening GUI at 80%
        setLoadingProgress("Intitializing OpenGL ...", 60);
        // Create video panel to hold Kinect feed
        testpanel = new VideoPanel();
        // Set the panel as the Kinect video feed display
        testkinect.setViewer(testpanel);
        // Add the new panel to the panel repository and center it inside
        mainpanel.add(testpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        int y;   // y-coordinate for the line
        int i;   // loop control variable
        y = 50;  // y starts at 50 for the first line
        for ( i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
            bounds.drawLine(100, y, 300, y);
            y = y + 10;  // increase y by 10 before drawing the next line.
        }

        bounds2.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

         JFrame f = new JFrame();
          f.setSize(400, 400);
          f.add(new KinectTest());
          f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          f.setVisible(true);

        // Test methods for the skeleton
        System.out.println("Skeleton Test Body Orientation: " + testskeleton.getBodyOrientation());
        System.out.println("Skeleton Test Torso Position: " + testskeleton.getTorsoOrientation());
        System.out.println("Skeleton Test Joint Orientations: " + testskeleton.getJointOrientations());
        System.out.println("Skeleton Test Joint Positions: " + testskeleton.getJointPositions());

        // Test methods for the video frame
        System.out.println("VideoFrame Test Height: " + testpanel.getHeight());
        System.out.println("VideoFrame Test Width: " + testpanel.getWidth());
```

As you can see, I am trying three different ways of displaying a shape but none show.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check out the example called KinectViewerApp found on their [website](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/download.php).

```
package j4kdemo.kinectviewerapp;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import edu.ufl.digitalworlds.gui.DWApp;
import edu.ufl.digitalworlds.j4k.J4K1;
import edu.ufl.digitalworlds.j4k.J4K2;
import edu.ufl.digitalworlds.j4k.J4KSDK;

/*
 * Copyright 2011-2014, Digital Worlds Institute, University of 
 * Florida, Angelos Barmpoutis.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * When this program is used for academic or research purposes, 
 * please cite the following article that introduced this Java library: 
 * 
 * A. Barmpoutis. "Tensor Body: Real-time Reconstruction of the Human Body 
 * and Avatar Synthesis from RGB-D', IEEE Transactions on Cybernetics, 
 * October 2013, Vol. 43(5), Pages: 1347-1356. 
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
 * met:
 *     * Redistributions of source code must retain this copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce this
 * copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer
 * in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
 * distribution.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KinectViewerApp extends DWApp implements ChangeListener
{

    Kinect myKinect;
    ViewerPanel3D main_panel;
    JSlider elevation_angle;
    JCheckBox near_mode;
    JCheckBox seated_skeleton;
    JCheckBox show_infrared;
    JButton turn_off;
    JComboBox depth_resolution;
    JComboBox video_resolution;
    JCheckBox show_video;
    JCheckBox mask_players;
    JLabel accelerometer;

    public void GUIsetup(JPanel p_root) {


        if(System.getProperty("os.arch").toLowerCase().indexOf("64")<0)
        {
            if(DWApp.showConfirmDialog("Performance Warning", "<html><center><br>WARNING: You are running a 32bit version of Java.<br>This may reduce significantly the performance of this application.<br>It is strongly adviced to exit this program and install a 64bit version of Java.<br><br>Do you want to exit now?</center>"))
                System.exit(0);
        }

        setLoadingProgress("Intitializing Kinect...",20);
        myKinect=new Kinect();


        if(!myKinect.start(Kinect.DEPTH| Kinect.COLOR |Kinect.SKELETON |Kinect.XYZ|Kinect.PLAYER_INDEX))
        {
            DWApp.showErrorDialog("ERROR", "<html><center><br>ERROR: The Kinect device could not be initialized.<br><br>1. Check if the Microsoft's Kinect SDK was succesfully installed on this computer.<br> 2. Check if the Kinect is plugged into a power outlet.<br>3. Check if the Kinect is connected to a USB port of this computer.</center>");
            //System.exit(0); 
        }

        //System.out.println(((J4K2)myKinect.getJ4KClass()).getIndex());
        //myKinect.computeUV(true);
        //myKinect.setNearMode(true);

        near_mode=new JCheckBox("Near mode");
        near_mode.setSelected(false);
        near_mode.addActionListener(this);
        if(myKinect.getDeviceType()!=J4KSDK.MICROSOFT_KINECT_1) near_mode.setEnabled(false);

        seated_skeleton=new JCheckBox("Seated skeleton");
        seated_skeleton.addActionListener(this);
        if(myKinect.getDeviceType()!=J4KSDK.MICROSOFT_KINECT_1) seated_skeleton.setEnabled(false);

        elevation_angle=new JSlider();
        elevation_angle.setMinimum(-27);
        elevation_angle.setMaximum(27);
        elevation_angle.setValue((int)myKinect.getElevationAngle());
        elevation_angle.setToolTipText("Elevation Angle ("+elevation_angle.getValue()+" degrees)");
        elevation_angle.addChangeListener(this);

        turn_off=new JButton("Turn off");
        turn_off.addActionListener(this);

        depth_resolution=new JComboBox();
        if(myKinect.getDeviceType()==J4KSDK.MICROSOFT_KINECT_1)
        {
            depth_resolution.addItem("80x60");
            depth_resolution.addItem("320x240");
            depth_resolution.addItem("640x480");
            depth_resolution.setSelectedIndex(1);
        }
        else if(myKinect.getDeviceType()==J4KSDK.MICROSOFT_KINECT_2)
        {
            depth_resolution.addItem("512x424");
            depth_resolution.setSelectedIndex(0);
        }
        depth_resolution.addActionListener(this);

        video_resolution=new JComboBox();
        if(myKinect.getDeviceType()==J4KSDK.MICROSOFT_KINECT_1)
        {
            video_resolution.addItem("640x480");
            video_resolution.addItem("1280x960");
            video_resolution.setSelectedIndex(0);
        }
        else if(myKinect.getDeviceType()==J4KSDK.MICROSOFT_KINECT_2)
        {
            video_resolution.addItem("1920x1080"); 
            video_resolution.setSelectedIndex(0);
        }


        video_resolution.addActionListener(this);

        show_infrared=new JCheckBox("Infrared");
        show_infrared.setSelected(false);
        show_infrared.addActionListener(this);

        show_video=new JCheckBox("Show texture");
        show_video.setSelected(false);
        show_video.addActionListener(this);

        mask_players=new JCheckBox("Mask Players");
        mask_players.setSelected(false);
        mask_players.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel controls=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,6));
        controls.add(new JLabel("Depth Stream:"));
        controls.add(depth_resolution);
        controls.add(mask_players);
        controls.add(near_mode);
        controls.add(seated_skeleton);
        accelerometer=new JLabel("0,0,0");
        controls.add(accelerometer);


        controls.add(new JLabel("Texture Stream:"));
        controls.add(video_resolution);
        controls.add(show_infrared);

        controls.add(show_video);
        controls.add(elevation_angle);

        controls.add(turn_off);



        setLoadingProgress("Intitializing OpenGL...",60);
        main_panel=new ViewerPanel3D();
        main_panel.setShowVideo(false);
        myKinect.setViewer(main_panel);
        myKinect.setLabel(accelerometer);

        p_root.add(main_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p_root.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public void GUIclosing()
    {
        myKinect.stop();
    }

    private void resetKinect()
    {
        if(turn_off.getText().compareTo("Turn on")==0) return;

        myKinect.stop();
        int depth_res=J4K1.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_INVALID;
        if(depth_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==0) myKinect.setDepthResolution(80, 60);//  depth_res=J4K1.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_80x60;
        else if(depth_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==1) myKinect.setDepthResolution(320, 240);//depth_res=J4K1.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_320x240;
        else if(depth_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==2) myKinect.setDepthResolution(640, 480);//depth_res=J4K1.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480;

        int video_res=J4K1.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_INVALID;
        if(video_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==0) myKinect.setColorResolution(640, 480);//video_res=J4K1.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480;
        else if(video_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==1) myKinect.setDepthResolution(1280, 960);//video_res=J4K1.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_1280x960;

        int flags=Kinect.SKELETON;
        flags=flags|Kinect.COLOR;
        flags=flags|Kinect.DEPTH;
        flags=flags|Kinect.XYZ;
        if(show_infrared.isSelected()) {flags=flags|Kinect.INFRARED; myKinect.updateTextureUsingInfrared(true);}
        else myKinect.updateTextureUsingInfrared(false);

        myKinect.start(flags);
        if(show_video.isSelected())myKinect.computeUV(true);
        else myKinect.computeUV(false);
        if(seated_skeleton.isSelected())myKinect.setSeatedSkeletonTracking(true);
        if(near_mode.isSelected()) myKinect.setNearMode(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        createMainFrame("Kinect Viewer App");
        app=new KinectViewerApp();
        setFrameSize(730,570,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void GUIactionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==near_mode)
        {
            if(near_mode.isSelected()) myKinect.setNearMode(true);
            else myKinect.setNearMode(false);
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==seated_skeleton)
        {
            if(seated_skeleton.isSelected()) myKinect.setSeatedSkeletonTracking(true);
            else myKinect.setSeatedSkeletonTracking(false);
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==show_infrared)
        {
            resetKinect();
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==turn_off)
        {
            if(turn_off.getText().compareTo("Turn off")==0)
            {
                myKinect.stop();
                turn_off.setText("Turn on");
            }
            else
            {
                turn_off.setText("Turn off");
                resetKinect();
            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==depth_resolution)
        {
            resetKinect();
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==video_resolution)
        {
            resetKinect();
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==show_video)
        {
            main_panel.setShowVideo(show_video.isSelected());
            if(show_video.isSelected()) myKinect.computeUV(true);
            else myKinect.computeUV(false);
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==mask_players)
        {
            myKinect.maskPlayers(mask_players.isSelected());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==elevation_angle)
        {
            if(!elevation_angle.getValueIsAdjusting())
            {
                myKinect.setElevationAngle(elevation_angle.getValue());
                elevation_angle.setToolTipText("Elevation Angle ("+elevation_angle.getValue()+" degrees)");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you have the view set up, you can try to get the tracked skeletons from the kinect:

```
    /*These methods convert the skeleton frame data received from a Kinect
      sensor to a Skeleton object.*/
    public static Skeleton getSkeleton(int id, boolean[] flags, float[] positions,
 float[] orientations, byte[] states, J4KSDK kinect);
    public static Skeleton getSkeleton(int id, boolean[] flags, float[] positions,
 float[] orientations, byte[] states, byte type);
    public static Skeleton getSkeleton(int id, boolean[] flags, float[] positions,
 float[] orientations, byte[] states, J4K1 kinect);
    public static Skeleton getSkeleton(int id, boolean[] flags, float[] positions,
 float[] orientations, byte[] states, J4K2 kinect);
```

and then get the corresponding joint from the skeleton. The following Joints could be of interest to you (see [this](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/Skeleton.php) for more info)

```
    *The following constant values enumerate the joints in the skeleton.*/
    public final static int WRIST_LEFT=6;
    public final static int HAND_LEFT=7;
    public final static int WRIST_RIGHT=10;
    public final static int HAND_RIGHT=11;
    public final static int HAND_TIP_LEFT=21;
    public final static int THUMB_LEFT=22;
    public final static int HAND_TIP_RIGHT=23;
    public final static int THUMB_RIGHT=24;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Link-only answers are not helpful, especially if the link should break.  Please provide the important aspects to your answer here, and provide links for reference.